# Rank2Types, "... would escape its scope" (beam)

Tags: haskell, haskell-beam

Currently I'm trying to use more of the composability of `beam`. Unfortunately I cannot figure out if what I am trying to do is even possible. What I am trying to do is write a function, that takes a `Q` query, and selects from the query twice, once unmodified and once wrapped into a "count(*)"-aggregate.

So far I got this function:

```
runPaginatedQuery :: ( QExprToIdentity res ~ a
                     , FromBackendRow Sqlite (QExprToIdentity res)
                     , ProjectibleWithPredicate ValueContext SqliteExpressionSyntax res
                     , ProjectibleWithPredicate AnyType SqliteExpressionSyntax res
                     )
                    => Connection -> Int -> Int
                    -> (forall s. Q SqliteSelectSyntax db s res)
                    -> IO ([a], Int)
runPaginatedQuery conn limit offset q = do
  (Just count) <- runBeamSqlite conn $ runSelectReturningOne $ select $ aggregate_ (const $ countAll_) q
  l <-  runBeamSqlite conn $ runSelectReturningList $ select q
  return (l,count)
```

The function type checks, but if I try to use it, e.g.

```
main = do
  conn <- open "test.db"
  (ss :: [Student], n) <- runPaginatedQuery conn 20 0 (all_ (_students schoolDb))
  print n
```

I get the following type error:

```
src/Main.hs:57:56: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘res0’
                     with ‘StudentT (QExpr SqliteExpressionSyntax s)’
        because type variable ‘s’ would escape its scope
      This (rigid, skolem) type variable is bound by
        a type expected by the context:
          forall s. Q SqliteSelectSyntax SchoolDb s res0
        at src/Main.hs:57:27-81
      Expected type: Q SqliteSelectSyntax SchoolDb s res0
        Actual type: Q SqliteSelectSyntax
                       SchoolDb
                       s
                       (StudentT
                          (QExpr
                             (Database.Beam.Backend.SQL.SQL92.Sql92SelectTableExpressionSyntax
                                (Database.Beam.Backend.SQL.SQL92.Sql92SelectSelectTableSyntax
                                   SqliteSelectSyntax))
                             s))
    • In the fourth argument of ‘runPaginatedQuery’, namely
        ‘(all_ (_students schoolDb))’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        (ss :: [Student], n) <- runPaginatedQuery
                                  conn 20 0 (all_ (_students schoolDb))
      In the expression:
        do conn <- open "test.db"
           (ss :: [Student], n) <- runPaginatedQuery
                                     conn 20 0 (all_ (_students schoolDb))
           print "hi"
   |
57 |   (ss :: [Student], n) <- runPaginatedQuery conn 20 0 (all_ (_students schoolDb))
   |                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm having trouble understanding the error message.

*Edit:* It seems that what I am trying to achieve is currently not possible, hence I accepted @chi's answer as it has a good explanation *why* it is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `runPaginatedQuery` requires the result type `res` of the query not to depend on `s`. But yours does.

```
 Expected type: Q SqliteSelectSyntax SchoolDb s res0
    Actual type: Q SqliteSelectSyntax
                   SchoolDb
                   s
                   (StudentT (QExpr
                   (Database.Beam.Backend.SQL.SQL92.Sql92SelectTableExpressionSyntax
                   (Database.Beam.Backend.SQL.SQL92.Sql92SelectSelectTableSyntax
                   SqliteSelectSyntax))
                   s))
               -- ^^^
```

I can't see any easy fix. The type of `runPaginatedQuery` looks too restrictive.

Intuitively, it should take something like `(forall s. Q SqliteSelectSyntax db s (F s))` where `F` is some type-level function, required to make `QExprToIdentity (F s)` to be independent from `s`. We can't however universally quantify on type-level functions `F` in Haskell.

Your code is close to requiring this, but implicitly requires `F s` itself to be a type `res` which is independent from `s`, which is too much.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way I could solve the ambiguity by using `TypeApplications`? I could not figure out how, but maybe instead of requiring `F`, I could pass `res0` via an explicit type application? I'm not particularly set on this specific form of `runPaginatedQuery`; I'm just trying to factor out a "pagination" pattern.

Comment: @Chirs I don't think type applications can help here, it's not an ambiguity issue. One would need type-level lambdas for this, but Haskell does not have them. I think I see what you are trying to achieve, and I think it's a nice problem, but I can't see a solution at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you ask for, in some specific cases:

The problem, is that for general `res` it's hard to do anything.
But really, you'd aggregate over some `table`. So if you massage the type,
it will type-check and work out, as we can get `s` into place where you had `res`.

```hs
runPaginatedQuery
    :: (Beamable table, FromBackendRow Sqlite (table Identity))
    => Connection -> Int -> Int
    -> (forall s. Q Sqlite db s (table (QExpr Sqlite s)))
    -> IO ([table Identity], Int)
```

This `runPaginatedQuery will accept your example

```
all_ (_students schoolDb)
```

query.

But won't accept more interesting queries like, i.e. which don't return whole table as is

```
do s <- all_ (_students schoolDb)
   return (studentFoo s)
```

I still think it's possible to make it work:

You'll need to define own type-class, with instances following
the structure of [`QExprToIdentity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/beam-core-0.8.0.0/docs/Database-Beam-Query.html#t:QExprToIdentity) (and [`ThreadRewritable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/beam-core-0.8.0.0/docs/Database-Beam-Query-Internal.html#t:ThreadRewritable) etc.).

I'm not saying it's easy, but I'm quite sure it's possible.

---

Btw, next time, please provide a more complete example so the people trying to help would start quickly:

Here's complete example you can load into GHCi:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Database.Beam
import Database.Beam.Sqlite
import Database.Beam.Sqlite.Connection
import Database.Beam.Sqlite.Syntax
import Database.SQLite.Simple


runPaginatedQuery
    :: (Beamable table, FromBackendRow Sqlite (table Identity))
    => Connection -> Int -> Int
    -> (forall s. Q Sqlite db s (table (QExpr Sqlite s)))
    -> IO ([table Identity], Int)
runPaginatedQuery conn limit offset q = do
  Just count <- runBeamSqlite conn $ runSelectReturningOne $ select $ aggregate_ (const $ countAll_) q
  l <-  runBeamSqlite conn $ runSelectReturningList $ select q
  return (l,count)

data StudentT f = Student
    { studentId :: C f Int
    }
  deriving (Generic, Beamable)

type Student = StudentT Identity

instance Table StudentT where
    newtype PrimaryKey StudentT f  = StudentId (C f Int)
      deriving (Generic, Beamable)

    primaryKey = StudentId . studentId

data SchoolDb f = SchoolDb
    { _students :: f (TableEntity StudentT) }
  deriving (Generic, Database be)

schoolDb :: DatabaseSettings be SchoolDb
schoolDb = defaultDbSettings

main = do
  conn <- open "test.db"
  (ss :: [Student], n) <- runPaginatedQuery conn 20 0 (all_ (_students schoolDb))
  print (n :: Int)
```